# cURL. How to save only url ....in file .txt

Tags: curl, sh

How to save a `.txt` file, only the url and beside the url`s, response from the server.

Example:

```
curl "www.google.com" >> result.txt
curl "www.earth.com" >> result.txt
```

I would like in the file `result.txt`, such a result:

```
www.google.com - HTTP 200 OK

www.earth.com - HTTP 200 OK
```

Comment: What is the reason to save url? You know it without curl.

Comment: I would like to save url and beside him to the status of the response.
Example: www.google.pl - HTTP/1.1 200 OK . But I do not know how to do it.

Comment: [`man curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) reveals the `-I` option for this.  But you should really edit your question to properly explain what exactly you want and which part of it you are having trouble with.

Comment: Hi. I edited the question of what exactly include I would get in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some shell script, for example, curl.sh:

```
#/usr/bin/sh
echo $1 `curl $1` > test.txt
```

and call this script instead of curl itself, `curl.sh www.google.pl`